# See all variables passed to the view

Tags: kohana

Is there any possibility to see all variables passed to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view code, at the top you can do something like `<?php print_r(get_defined_vars()); ?>`, which will give a formatted text output of all the variables in scope at the moment.

Comment: Simple solution is the best solution. In Smarty there is a separate function to that and I forget about native one. Thanks.

Comment: PaulP
Modern Frameworks have so rare HTML in View Code, that there is no Template Engine needed any more. The most HTML there is bound in Methods and there can be much Views with no piece of HTML Code.
So I would say, if you need Smarty&co. you do something wrong or you are yust a bit outdated...